# C# DataBind with Lists inside loops

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to bind a List to a Repeater. Here is my code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            CaseEnt MyCase = MyLib.IAdapters.CaseAdapter.GetCaseRecordForCaseNumber("14CF000810");
            List<Charge> charges = MyLib.IAdapters.ChargeAdapter.GetByCaseNumber("14CF000810");
            if (charges != null && charges.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Charge chg in charges)
                {
                    List <Sentence> sentences = MyLib.IAdapters.SentenceAdapter.GetByChargeObjectID(chg.ChargeObjectID);
                    rpt1.DataSource = sentences;
                    rpt1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

I've put stops in the code to check what values are flowing into the Lists. When the sentences List is being populated, it shows values, but when I check it when it's being assigned as the Datasource, it's blank.

What am I doing wrong?

I've been working at this for a while, and I've scoured the internet for answers, and no one seems to be able to help me. Any assistance would be appreciated, even if it's explaining a different way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Rational behind assigning a datasource to repeater in the `foreach` loop is hard to understand.

Every time the repeater is assigned the new set of sentences as a datasource, the previously bound data (i.e., sentences) will be removed, new sentences won't be appended.

In your case, the last instance of charge - `chg`, doesn't have any sentences and hence the value of `List <Sentence> sentences` inside `foreach` loop becomes `null`. That's the only case I can think of why it's behaving like this. You may want to put a breakpoint on this line to see if that's the case -

```
rpt1.DataSource = sentences;
```

If you want all the sentences from all the charges to be bound to Repeater control, you may want to collect all of them by your CaseNumber first, and then bind it once without `foreach` loop.

---

**UPDATE:**

---

You have written 2 methods - one to get list of charges for a given case number, and second, get a list of sentences for a given charge.

Instead, you can do either of these two-

- Write only one method that will get all the sentences for all the charges for a given case number. Get the result of this method in `List <Sentence>` object and bind it with Repeater control directly.
- Don't write any new method, but instead of binding a repeater in `foreach` loop, you can keep adding sentences for each charge in `List <Sentence>` object.

Like this:

```
List <Sentence> sentences;
foreach (Charge chg in charges)
{
    List <Sentence> sentencesForThisCharge = MyLib.IAdapters.SentenceAdapter.GetByChargeObjectID(chg.ChargeObjectID);
    if (null != sentencesForThisCharge) 
    {
        sentences.Add(sentencesForThisCharge);
    }
}

rpt1.DataSource = sentences;
rpt1.DataBind();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the time, really. I should explain I'm pretty new to C#. 

How would I go about doing that without the foreach loop? The only way to get the sentences is by the ChargeObjectID

Comment: Then I guess my question has to be, how do I pass the ChargeID to the second method, so it gets the correct sentences?

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the bind to the repeater, effectively overwriting what is already bound to it.

If you remove your sentences list and databind command outside of the loop it will work.

```
if (charges != null && charges.Count > 0)
        {
            List<Sentence> sentences = new List<Sentence>();
            foreach (Charge chg in charges)
            {
                sentences.AddRange(MyLib.IAdapters.SentenceAdapter.GetByChargeObjectID(chg.ChargeObjectID))

            }
            rpt1.DataSource = sentences;
            rpt1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! This works.  I have one followup question, though.

Now if I wanted to show different fields from both Charges AND Sentences in nested Repeaters in ASP.NET, how would I do that? Since if I try to DataBind the list outside of the context of that class it won't recognize it.

Comment: If you are using asp.net webforms, then you need the onitemdatabound event of the parent repeater. You can then bind the nested repeater within this event. Also if the above answer has solved your initial issue, please mark it as the accepted answer